# How do I sign in to chrome in the window, not a dialog box?

Tags: google-chrome

Sometimes I get prompted to sign in to Chrome in the actual window, but if I explicitly request to sign in to Chrome, it pops up a dialog box under the user button that goes away if I switch focus away from Chrome (for example, to retrieve my credentials from a password manager).

How can I get the sign-in box which stays in a Chrome window or tab?  I tried a few `chrome://` urls but haven't found the right setting.

Answer (score 1):

To get the sign-in in the window, not the dialog box, you can enter the following URL:

`chrome://chrome-signin/?source=0`